# Power App Subscription to run the power app

Tags: powerapps

If I share the power app with user in organization(Active directory), then do they need a power app subscription/Licence to run the power app. I want to create a simple data entry for and share it with users in organization.

Regards,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerPlatform licesing can quickly become a very complex topic.

**Its highly dependant on:**

- Which Office365 and Dynamics365 licensing your org has in place
- Whether your solution uses On-premise data
- Whether your solution uses Premium connectors
- etc.

*Generally speaking*, if everyone in your org has the correct Office365 license **AND** your solution uses only non-premium connectors (Sharepoint, Outlook365, OneDrive, etc.), you can expect your app to work for everyone at your org.

Please see **pg. 6** ("Power Appsuse rights included with Office 365licenses") and **Appendix B** of the latest PowerPlatform licensing guide (currently found here: https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/6/9568EFD0-403D-4AE4-95F0-7FACA2CCB2E4/Power%20Apps,%20Power%20Automate%20and%20Power%20Virtual%20Agents%20Licensing%20Guide%20-%20Dec%202020.pdf)